# How can I update a Model and do something with this object or other?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

My model has 7 fields, but I want update a only field. I'm using CBC(`generic.UpdateView`) with model and `form_class`. My forms works normally, but, 
I want do things depending on value for this Field.

I don't know what method override.

```
ModelA:
atribute_a
atribute_b
atribute_c
```

I need change only `atribute_a`, but `atribute_b` is a `dateTime`, and a I want update `atribute_b` with `timezone.now()` when update `atribute_a`, and after that I want update a another object with ForeignKey with `atribute_c` for example.

basically in a UpdateView, I want this:
In a some method(save, post, dispatch or other)

```
atribute_b = timezone.now()
if atribute_a == 'abc':
    ModelB.objects.filter(atribute_c=atribute_c).update(atribute_c = atribute_c+1)
```

Comment: Did  you look at [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/), I would check out the `post_save` and `pre_save` signals. You can also override the model's `save` method, but I don't think that's good practice

Comment: you can add `auto_now` to attribute_b

Comment: This a update, auto_now when object is created, I want the time when object will change. The signal is when, always object have changes, created or updated, I want make changes only in this casa?

Comment: How can I make Update with TemplateView??

Answer (score 0):

I used `def save(self, commit=True):` in my `forms.py`, and in my `view.py` I used `generic.UpdateView` with `model` and `form_class`.

code from my forms.

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['atribute_a']
        exclude = ['atribute_b', 'atribute_c']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.atribute_b = timezone.now()
        # do something with FK
```